# Process.StartTime in C#

Tags: c#

In C# the `StartTime` function shows only the user process run time. Are there other criteria?

Comment: Can you clarify?  What's the actual question here...?

Comment: -1, 99% of such questions can be answered precisely just by looking for 'StartTime' in MSDN Library.
I've got it installed on my machine so it takes really no time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean [Process.StartTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx), this is correct.  It provides the date and time when a specified process was started.